# How to create a Popover in iOS 7 in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have seen people creating popOver with UIPopOverController in Xcode for iPad. I need to get the same in my iPhone app. It was possible with the previous versions of Xcode when we could resize a UIViewController and creating it as a custom view. But is it still possible with iOS 7. If not is there any alternate solution to achieve something similar. Pls help...Pls find the sample image of popover

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: *"But is it still possible with iOS 7"* - Did you try it? Where is your code?

Comment: I tried a youtube tutorial but only thing is that I'm not able to link a view controller like shown in the tutorial. LL post u the link to the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Try [WEPopover](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wepopover).  It should provide you with the functionality you need, and more.

[image]